# VSCode: Group folders in explorer by the first letter

Tags: visual-studio-code, explorer

#### Problem

**I need to organize view of subfolders inside the exact folder in VSCode Explorer in a way [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUrBS.png)**, so the subfolders are grouped into corresponding intermediate folders, which are named by a single letter, representing the first letter of the subfolders. (preferably this should work automatically, but not necessary)

These intermediate **folders a, b, c ... should be "virtual"**. Actual location of the original subfolders shouldn't be changed.

#### I tried...

Surprisingly, i couldn't find appropriate VSCode Extension for this.

I have [achived desired behavior for files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfAkq.png), with `fileNesting` option, by manually creating files a, b, c ... and using such a pattern in the settings:

```json
"explorer.fileNesting.patterns": {
    "a": "a*",
    "b": "b*",
    "c": "c*",
    ...
}
```

But this doesn't affect folders.

Comment: add a feature request to the VSC repo